# ActionScript ternary operator

Tags: actionscript-3, ternary-operator

in action script

str is string var

```
str=(some condition)?" store true":"store false";
```

when i alert the str am not getting any message .....why am not getting

code:

```
[Bindable]
public var errVarMsg:String ;

errVarMsg="";
errVarMsg=(minfee<=maxfee)?"":"fee min > max\n";
Alert.show(errVarMsg);
```

Comment: Come on, post the real code. Your example does not allow for any kind of analysis.

Comment: So `minfee <= maxfee` holds, and `errVarMsg` becomes the empty string?

Comment: yes if the condition is true...when it's false also am not getting any message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `minfee` is less than or equal to `maxfee`, you'll get an empty alert which might be taken as no message. Change it to

```
minfee = 5;
maxfee = 10;
errVarMsg = (minfee <= maxfee) ? "min <= max" : "min > max";
Alert.show(errVarMsg);

minfee = 15;
maxfee = 10;
errVarMsg = (minfee <= maxfee) ? "min <= max" : "min > max";
Alert.show(errVarMsg);
```

Comment: when the condition is true i need errVarMsg to be empty....only if it's false i will alert...

Comment: Did you try this - did you get proper output as expected?